# how to put my java web application in a server?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, deployment, glassfish, installation

I made a **Java Web Application** with Netbeans. I used **JSF**, **PrimeFaces** and the **Glassfish Server**. Now I want to put my application in a server but i just dont have idea of how to do that. I think fist of all have to install Glassfish in the server. How do I do that? The server i will be using has **Windows Server 2008 Enterprise**. Do I have to look for a .exe to **install** **Glassfish**? The same to do with **Java**? I have already done the connection to the SQL Server database so that part must work. So please explain me step by step what i have to have, how to install and configure everything and how to try if everything worked please.

Thanks for Your answers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what your web application requires you will need to install more than just the glassfish server.

You need to install:

-Java jdk (required)

-Glassfish server (required)

-Database (if using one)

-Apache (if needed)

After you install everything, you need to deploy the war file of the application to the glassfish server. To do this you must first create a war file by 'cleaning and building' the app (option in netbeans). The war file will be located in one of the folders in the project.

Then you must log in to your glassfish admin console (located at `http://localhost:4848` if run on localhost) and click on one of the options in the left menu that lets you manage the applications on the server. There will then be an option that lets you add war files to the server.